# Which API of GoogleAnalytics I should use to retrieve name of the country through IP-address?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, google-analytics-api

I need to retrieve the name of the country using an IP address in my C# ASP.NET MVC 3 application programmatically. I want to use GoogleAnalytics API for it. Which API of GoogleAnalytics I should use to retrieve the name of the country through IP address?

Comment: I think you are confused with your APIs Google Analytics API doesn't store IP address.

Answer (score 2):

Hmm, why don't you use some webservice/site that does this instead?

Like http://ip-api.com/, http://freegeoip.net/ etc.
A quick serach for "get country from ip api" will give you some options :)

Comment: I havn't use neither GoogleAnalytics API nor freegeoip.net. I'll be very thankful if you give me an example about how to use one of abovementioned means to programmatically get country name using IP-address in C# application. Preferably in ASP.NET MVC 3.

Comment: HOW TO GET THE COUNTRY NAME VIA IP-ADDRESS PROGRAMMATICALLY IN C# ASP.NET MVC 3 APPLICATION?

Comment: Hey, no need to yell ;)

I think you should pick up some book on C#. Most of those above have some sort of api, so you can just make an request to their api and you get som json back which you have to read/parse.

I haven't done anything with .NET for many years so can't give you any better answer than the same google/bing-search you propably can make yourself :)